# How do I know when to use $\cos$, $\sin$, or $\tan$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know how to tell which one when you have two of the sides, but what if you only have one side and three angles? For example, what if you had to do the triangle

[image: triangle]

and the opposite was 80. How would you know if you had to use tan, cos, or sin to find a specific side?

Comment: "*If you only have one side and one angle?*"  You are told two angles, and the third angle is easy to calculate.  The second angle you are given?  $90^\circ$, notated by a square for the angle rather than a curve.

Comment: If you have only one known angle in a right triangle, that's the right angle. If an acute angle in a right triangle is known, you know all the angles.

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited the question

Comment: You can use sine, cosine, tan all trigonometric functions only for right angle triangle

Comment: Why do you learn 'patterns' by heart? Just read the definiton.

Comment: @ManjoyDas not necessarily true.  The trig functions applied to angles in triangles which are not right triangles might still be relevant.  See [law of sines and cosines](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-trig/hs-geo-solving-general-triangles/a/laws-of-sines-and-cosines-review).  In any case for here, what is preventing you from continuing?  Making a choice?  Then... make a choice and see if it works... you have multiple options for this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Trig functions relate to right triangles. They apply to the other two angles that are not 90 degrees use the following definitions:

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

The terms *opposing* and *adjacent* applying to sides which are not the hypotenuse.

Then

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \sin ({\rm angle}) &  = \frac{ {\rm opposing} }{ {\rm hypotenuse} } \\
 \cos ({\rm angle}) &  = \frac{ {\rm adjacent} }{ {\rm hypotenuse} } \\  
 \tan ({\rm angle}) &  = \frac{ {\rm opposing} }{ {\rm adjacent} } \\
\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\cos(\alpha)$ is defined by:
$$\frac{a}{c}$$
where $c$ is the hypotenuse and $a$ is the side adiacent to the angle $\alpha$. 
The $\sin(\alpha)$ is defined by:
$$\frac{b}{c}$$
where $b$ is the side opposite to the angle $\alpha$ and $c$ the hypotenuse.
The $\tan(\alpha)$ is defined as the ratio between $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\alpha)$, so:
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{b}{a}$$

In your case, you have first to calculate the lenght of $c$, using:
$$c=\frac{b}{\sin(75°)}=\frac{80}{\sin(75°)}$$
in fact, we know by what we have stated before that:
$$80=c\cdot\sin(75°) \leftrightarrow c=\frac{80}{\sin(75°)}$$
With this, you can find $a$, so:
$$a=c\cdot \cos(\alpha)=80\cdot \tan(75°)$$

---

As @David G. Stork has pointed out, a mnemonical phrase you can learn is:
"SOHCAHTOA (which reminds us of "sock it to me"): Sine = Opposite/ Hypotenuse; Cosine = Adjacent/ Hypotenuse; Tangent = Opposite/ Adjacent."

Comment: In school we learned ***SOHCAHTOA*** (which reminds us of "sock it to me"):  ***S***ine = ***O***pposite/ ***H***ypotenuse; ***C***osine = ***A***djacent/ ***H***ypotenuse; ***T***angent = ***O***pposite/ ***A***djacent.

Comment: @David G. Stork: I don't know this. I will include in the post.

Comment: No need to be "sorry"!  We're all here to teach each other....

Comment: How did you know it was ```b/sin(75)``` and not ```b/cos(75)```?

Comment: @TheRealTengri: please see my edits.

Comment: @David G. Stork You too? I was always averse to mnemonics in math because they remove the math from an idea for the sake of convenience, which by experience I know leads to little comprehension in people

Comment: Yep.  Me too.  I find mnemonics occasionally useful, so long as I understand the underlying science or math, but here it is just a naming convention, so a mnemonic is perfectly acceptable, in my opinion.  I was surprised when my very distinguished BS thesis advisor, Dr. Edwin Land of Polaroid, kept using little phrases and mnemonics, but ultimately realized that this was one of his tricks for keeping so very much at hand, intellectually.

Comment: @TgeRealTwngri: if this anser has been useful, mybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is.... don't start with the trig function, start with the sides, then with that information, determine which trig ratio you need.

For example, suppose I know that the opposite side is 80, and I wish to find the hypotenuse. First off, build the fraction (and try to put the unknown in the denominator; it's just easier that way)
$$\frac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}} $$

Now, look for the trig ratio that matches. 
$$\sin \theta = \frac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$$
Finally, just make substitutions for known quantities
$$\sin 75^\circ = \frac{80}{x}$$